# What is the difference between Docker Compose YAML version 1 and version 2?

Tags: docker, containers, yaml, docker-compose

I am using YAML files for the first time for writing `docker-compose.yaml`. Here I came to know that there are two Compose file format versions available for YAML files. Which one do I need to use while writing `docker-compose.yaml` and why? What is the exact difference?

Comment: I guess you mean `docker-compose.yml` v1 and v2. Differences are identified here https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#versioning Since you are just beginning, probably start with v2 as it's the current standard and supports features that not available in v1.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is confusing. On the one hand there is the YAML specification version (among others):

- YAML version 1.1 released in 2005
- YAML version 1.2 released in 2009

So there is no YAML version 2 (but there was a YAML 1.0)

On the other hand there is the version in the docker-compose file, which if not specified defaults to **the string** `1`. Since version 1.6 of `docker-compose` it also supports version `2` (also a string) docker compose files. Main difference is that that in version 2 you have all services under the specific `services` key. This is of course much more flexible in extending that the original version 1 toplevel-key-is-service specification.

However both version 1 and version 2 compose files use the old YAML 1.1 standard, which among other things causes you to have to quote port mappings, because under YAML 1.1 these could be interpreted (depending on the port value) as sexagesimals. YAML 1.2 doesn't have this problem, but docker-compose relies PyYAML and that was not updated after 2009 to support YAML 1.2

The best info on the actual differences you find IMO in [the section on how to upgrade](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#upgrading) from compose version 1. to compose version 2

I have made small wrapper script [`dcw`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.dcw) that preprocesses the version 2 docker-compose files as YAML 1.2 (so you don't have to worry about YAML 1.1. idiosyncrasies), it also allows you to set environment variables from within the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: thanks a lot, It's help to understand the difference.